# Where do i put the listener methods for buttons on dom-bind template

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I am using polymer starter kit which has some `paper-icon-buttons` on the `paper-toolbar` by default.

```
<body unresolved class="fullbleed layout vertical">
  <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
  <paper-drawer-panel id="paperDrawerPanel" forceNarrow>
   <paper-header-panel main mode="flex">
    <!-- Main Toolbar -->
    <paper-toolbar id="mainToolbar">

      <!-- Toolbar icons -->
        <paper-icon-button icon="search"></paper-icon-button>
        <paper-icon-button icon="refresh" on-tap='refreshTapped'></paper-icon-button>

      </paper-toolbar>

    </paper-header-panel>
  </paper-drawer-panel>
</template>

<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
```

How can I add an `on-tap` listener on the refresh button?
I have tried to add the listener method in `scripts/app.js` like shown below but still the method cannot be found.

```
function refreshTapped(){ 
  document.querySelector('#myDialog').toggle();
}
```

When i click on the button i get this on the browser console:

```
`[dom-bind::_createEventHandler]: listener method `refreshTapped` not defined`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the "scripts/app.js" file and add your function like this:

```
app.refreshTapped = function() {
    console.log('tapped');
  }
```

just like the app.onMenuSelect example that is already in there

Answer (score 0):

I call the `paper-drawer-panel` in `layouts-element` and call the function in a `onClick()` of `JavaScript`.

I was the same with:

> [dom-bind::_createEventHandler]: listener method `onDataRouteClick` not defined

I call the function with:

```
onClick="app.onDataRouteClick()"
```

I work `polymer` ^ 1.0